# File input's input event and/or change event fire in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, Edge or IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a Drag&Drop file uploader, and it works fine in Chrome and Opera. Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer however, are giving me headaches.

I have the following minimal example (with console logging for convenience):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("Document is ready.");

      document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { // Fires on drop event
        console.log("Drop event recorded on document.");
        input = document.querySelector("#file-input"); // Find file input
        input.files = e.dataTransfer.files; // Set dropped files into file input
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });

      document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
        console.log("Dragover event recorded on document.");
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });
    });

    function uploadFiles() {
      console.log("Function uploadFiles() called, it works in this browser!");
      // File upload logic here
      alert("Got new file(s), it works in this browser!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test input event</h1>
  <p>Drop file(s) anywhere on the page to trigger the input event. The event is fired as expected in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer 11.</p>
  <p>When the event is fired, you will be notified by an alert message.</p>
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" oninput="console.log('oninput fired on input element.'); uploadFiles();" disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome and Opera runs this page as we'd expect. The events are fired at the appropriate times, and the uploadFiles() function is eventually called.

Firefox, Edge and IE are able to fire the dragover and drop events, but the input event on the input element is not triggered when the file(s) are inserted from the dataTransfer.

I've been searching all day, and have found several similar questions, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the `input` event after you appended the file content, or even better call `uploadFiles` in the drop event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("Document is ready.");

      document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { // Fires on drop event
        console.log("Drop event recorded on document.");
        input = document.querySelector("#file-input"); // Find file input
        input.files = e.dataTransfer.files; // Set dropped files into file input
         $("#file-input").trigger('input');//trigger the upload
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });

      document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
        console.log("Dragover event recorded on document.");
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });
    });

    function uploadFiles() {
      console.log("Function uploadFiles() called, it works in this browser!");
      // File upload logic here
      alert("Got new file(s), it works in this browser!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test input event</h1>
  <p>Drop file(s) anywhere on the page to trigger the input event. The event is fired as expected in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, Edge or Internet Explorer 11.</p>
  <p>When the event is fired, you will be notified by an alert message.</p>
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" oninput="console.log('oninput fired on input element.'); uploadFiles();" disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This causes Chrome and Opera to trigger the input event twice, as it will be triggered as normal when setting input.files, and again on $("#file-input").trigger(), thus uploading the file twice.

Comment: then call `uploadFiles` in the drop event, why do you need the input for?

Comment: I'm using it for a button alternative, but that is absolutely true, and I feel ashamed now. Thank you for this, I guess it makes one go blind after sitting on the same problem for a full day... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @madalinivascu pointed out in a comment to his answer, there's no need to go via the input for my purposes, as I can call `uploadFiles()` directly from the drop event callback function after rewriting `uploadFiles()` and its callers slightly. Now it works in all major browsers!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) { // Fires on drop event
        uploadFiles(e.dataTransfer.files); // Call uploadFiles() on drop
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });

      document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior (like opening the file(s) in the browser tab)
      });
    });

    function uploadFiles(files) {
      // File upload logic here
      alert("It works!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test drop event</h1>
  <p>
    Drop file(s) anywhere on the page to trigger the drop event.
    The function uploadFiles() is now called as expected in all major browsers (not tested in Safari tho).
  </p>
  <!-- Input is now obsolete unless you want to provide an alternative file selection method -->
  <input type="file" multiple id="file-input" oninput="uploadFiles(this.files);" disabled/>
</body>
</html>
```